# Method Not Found: UseConsistentNullReferenceBehavior when downgrading from Framework 4.5 to 4.0

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, windows-xp, .net-4.5

I have a VS 2012 C#/WPF solution that was originally targeting the .Net Framework 4.5. When I went to deploy it, however, I found that 4.5 does not support WinXP. WinXP is still on the supported list for the 4.0 framework, so I changed all the projects in my solution to target the 4.0 Client framework.

Everything builds and publishes without error, and it installs and runs fine on Win7. However, the app fails on WinXP with this message:

> Error loading preferences and configuration data. Method not found: 'Void System.Data.Objects.ObjectContextOptions.set_UseConsistentNullReferenceBehavior(Boolean)'.

I have searched my solution for UseConsistentNullReferenceBehavior, but I cannot find it anywhere.

Any thoughts on how to fix this? I would rather not have to create a new solution and new projects, but that's probably my next step.

Comment: Realizing that the code generation templates (the *.tt) files under the .emdx file) had already been generated when the solution was targeting the .Net Framework 4.5 / Entity Framework 5, I deleted the model in my data objects project, and then created it again while targeting the .Net Framework 4.0 / Entity Framework 4.

Unfortunately, the code generated for this new model was still trying to use the Entity Framework 5 because it referenced the System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure namespace.

It appears that once you target .Net Framework 4.5 in your solution you cannot back it down to 4.0.

Comment: You should write the solution in an answer and accept it. Your comment here helped me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realizing that the code generation templates (the *.tt) files under the .emdx file) had already been generated when the solution was targeting the .Net Framework 4.5 / Entity Framework 5, I deleted the model in my data objects project, and then created it again while targeting the .Net Framework 4.0 / Entity Framework 4. Unfortunately, the code generated for this new model was still trying to use the Entity Framework 5 because it referenced the System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure namespace.

It appears that once you target .Net Framework 4.5 in your solution you cannot back it down to 4.0